# Convert razor model to json and use to angular

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs, razor

I'm trying to use `AngularJs` to `MVC5`, but my problem is I don't have any Idea how to get the data from razor `@model` using `AngularJs`.

So I decide to convert the `@Model` to json but it's not working.

**_Layout.cshtml**

Razor @model

```
@model IEnumerable<GoActive.Models.ActiveDirectory2>
```

AngularJs

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        var response = @Model.AsRawJson(); // But .AsRawJson(); is not allowed in this one.
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could convert the entire server-side model into a JS object using [Json.Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx)

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

In case if you Model is a collection then you can use a sequential for loop to iterate over your model collection. So the complete code would be something like..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
     for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        alert(model[i].myValue);

        // Do Something with your model
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It says `Syntax Error: Returns markup that is not HTML encoded`. **Note:** *I use angularjs.*

Comment: @Leonel, You should wrap `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` in single quotes: `var model = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))')`;

Answer (score 0):

try this once.

```html
<div data-ng-init="angularModel=@razorModel"></div>
```